# Disable specific OpenSSH host keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, configuration

The general idea I've been finding on this is that if you remove the HostKey line which corresponds to a specific key, the key will stop being generated. For whatever reason though, my sshd_config only lists one HostKey at /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key, and every time I delete the extra keys and restart sshd, it regenerates both the ssh_host_dsa_key and ssh_host_key files. Aside from digging through source and recompiling OpenSSH myself, is there any way to enforce that it not create a specific host key?

Running OpenSSH 6.1p1-4.fc18 on Fedora 18 x86_64 if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the `/etc/sysconfig/sshd` file and change the `AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS` variable:

```
AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS=NO
```

or

```
AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS=RSAONLY
```

Also ensure that you only have `Protocol 2` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know there's *another* file I can configure.